# Exact planar electrical flow

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-theory, planar-graphs, physics

Consider an electrical network modeled as a planar graph G, where each edge represents a 1Ω resistor.  **How quickly can we compute the *exact* effective resistance between two vertices in G?**  Equivalently, how quickly can we compute the *exact* current flowing along each edge if we attach a 1V battery to two vertices in G?

Kirchhoff's well-known [voltage and current laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws) reduce this problem to solving a system of linear equations with one variable per edge.  More recent results — described explicitly by [Klein and Randić (1993)](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01164627) but implicit in earlier work of [Doyle and Snell (1984)](http://math.dartmouth.edu/~doyle/docs/walks/walks.pdf) — reduce the problem to solving a linear system with one variable per vertex, representing that node's *potential*; the matrix for this linear system is the Laplacian matrix of the graph.

Either linear system can be solved exactly in $O(n^{3/2})$ time using nested dissection and planar separators [[Lipton Rose Tarjan 1979](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2156840?uid=3739656&uid=2&uid=4&uid=3739256&sid=21101650334243)].  **Is this the fastest algorithm known?**

Recent seminal results of Spielman, Teng, and others imply that the Laplacian system in *arbitrary* graphs can be solved *approximately* in near-linear time.  See [[Koutis Miller Peng 2010](http://arxiv.org/abs/1003.2958)] for the current best running time, and [this amazing article](https://simonsfoundation.org/features/science-news/mathematics-and-physical-science/network-solutions/) by Erica Klarreich at the Simons Foundation for a high-level overview.  But I'm specifically interested in *exact* algorithms for *planar* graphs.

Assume a model of computation that supports exact real arithmetic in constant time.

Comment: the Klarreich article mentions applications in (optimizing) max flow near the end and is already out of date due to the recent Orlin $O(m \cdot n)$ breakthrough, which is apparently not related to the Laplacian direction of attack. see also this recent tcs.se question, [Are any of the state of the art Maximum Flow algorithms practical?](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/16347/)

Answer (score 14):

Using nested dissections you can even solve a linear system (based on a planar graph) in $O(\sqrt{n^\omega})$. This was for example noted in a [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/0908.0488)  I have with Günter Rote and Ares Ribó and in this [paper by Alon and Yuster](http://www.tau.ac.il/~nogaa/PDFS/sparsesystem.pdf).

The former paper also contains an approach how to compute the pairwise resistances between vertices on a a common face in $O(\sqrt{n^\omega})$. This [paper by Kenyon](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1203.1256v1.pdf) might also contain helpful ideas.